# Reload NSMenu with set localization

Tags: macos, cocoa, localization, nsmenu

I want to update application NSMenu with selected by user localization.
How to do it?
I want to create NSMenu in xib file and localize it. When user press button I want to change all my app localization. How can load NSMenu from specific localized bundle? Can I do it without reload app?

Answer (score 0):

> When user press button I want to change all my app localization.

I achieved this, but to do so I had to implement a paradigm of 1) set app to new lang pref 2) launch tiny helper app 3) quit main app 4) app relaunches in new lang pref (by helper app).

It usually happens in the blink of an eye, and it's cool as heck, but it's a LOT of work.  And of course it's kind of nuclear.  There are lots of very very clever things on the web, here at SO, too, of ways to twist what your app gets from the main OS calls to get localized strings from your own app's bundle, but none of them touch the issue of some of the menu bar items that apple adds to your app without your even doing anything.

As far as those, once your app launches, the lang pref it gets from defaults is cached into the OS, and nothing you can do will change it... until your app relaunches.

And then there are some strings like in buttons of system controlled dialogs that will come up in the lang of the boot drive pref and you can't change them no matter what.

But if you're ok with getting like 80 percent of the stuff in your app dynamically localized, when the user hits a button, keep googling until you find the thread at SO here I'm talking about... keywords maybe "dynamic, localization, something", and if you really can't find it say so cuz I've got it bookmarked somewhere, but probably on another boot drive.